# Excel popup window after using macro

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros, vba, popups

This is the excel sheet i am using

[image]

When i run this macro

```
   Sub Value_fla()

    Dim k As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    k = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Range("D2:D" & k).Formula = Range("D2").Formula
    Range("F2:F" & k).Formula = Range("F2").Formula
    Range("G2:G" & k).Formula = Range("G2").Formula

    Range("D3:D" & k) = Range("D3:D" & k).Value
    Range("F3:F" & k) = Range("F3:F" & k).Value
    Range("G3:G" & k) = Range("G3:G" & k).Value

  End Sub
```

i got this popup window
[image]

and if i press cancel macro works fine. How can i get rid off this window??
any tips??

Excel version 2010

Comment: It seems that some data in your sheet a linked to 'Data.xls' file. Possibly, Excel can't find the file when trying to refresh data. Question, what you need to do? Is is allowed to break all links to external files?? Or maybe you could better find that missing file and set the location of it. We advise you accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the formula you are working with inside the sheet has a reference to another file, so when run your macro, it is looking for you to update that file reference.

I suggest you go to [the speadsheet page](http://spreadsheetpage.com/) if you want to have proper answers to your question.  I also suggest clarifying what you are asking for.